# How to make VScode .net core debug for all files not just selected ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I use VScode and I am learning C#, but I am having trouble with debugging.
When I use the dotnet console it creates a *.Net core* console only for that file.

How can I debug C# code from any folder without the hassle of changing the `.json`?
I have been trying different things and still can't sort it out.

With python, there is a python current file.
Does C# have something like this?

Comment: You might develop your own VSCode extension to fill the gaps, but I don't see anything for that yet.